# Change 0 values to nan values in numpy array changes everything to nan

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I have numpy array with the shape of (1212,2117).
The array contains pixels with value 0 or values that are rgeater than 0 , looks like this:
[image]

I want to give the 0 pixels value of no data. I have tried to do it this way:

```
arr=arr.astype('float')
arr[arr==0]=np.nan
```

It seems like the result is chart that is all NaN.with one little square:

```
plt.imshow(test)
```

[image]

However it seems like all the values were changes, as if I check what is the max or min value of this array I get nan:

```
test.max()
>>>nan

test.min()
>>>nan
```

**I would like to understand why I get this result and how can I correctly give no data values for pixels with value of 0**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the reason and solution in the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html#numpy.amax) (Notes section).

> NaN values are propagated, that is if at least one item is NaN, the
> corresponding max value will be NaN as well. To ignore NaN values
> (MATLAB behavior), please use nanmax.

```
np.nanmax(arr)
# and
np.nanmin(arr))
```

Should give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Make a list

Iterate through every pixel, check if it is a nan, then append 0, if not then append the number.

np.array(your array)

Although it is unpythonic, it may get the job done.